# Как правильно создавать ветки в Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

В проекте есть ветка `dev`, от которой создаются ветки для фичей, потом эти фичи мержатся в эту ветку и далее в `master`. Начал работать, создал новую ветку `feature1` от `dev`, сделал пару изменений в стилях, запушил на `gitlab`, создал мерж реквест. Далее, снова создал новую ветку `feature2` от `dev`, добавил пару изменений в стилях, создал мерж реквест и так несколько раз. **Прощу заметить, что во всех созданных мерж реквестах изменения были сделаны только в одном файле!**  В итоге у меня сейчас 5 мерж реквестов. При мерже одного из них появляется конфликт в других, и это правильно, потому что при следующем мерже одного из мерж реквестов в ветку dev, файл над которым работал начитает отличаться в других мерж реквестах.

Вот схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: нужно ли при создании новой ветки `feature2` от ветки `dev`, получать изменения из предыдущей ветки `feature1`?

Пока что единственным решением этой проблемы которое приходит в голову, создавать новую ветку `feature2` от ветки `dev`, потом просто пулить изменения из предыдущей ветки `feature1`. В этом случае во всех последующих ветках будут все предыдущие изменения.

Comment: если она не была замерждена, то не нужно.

Comment: @Denisoed Почитай [эту](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33575056/) книгу. Страница 67. Там все описано, по твоему случаю.

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? В итоге в мастер-ветке останутся только изменения из feature 5, а всех остальных не будет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Но как тогда избавиться от конфликтов? Если замержить любую из веток, и после попытаться замержить другую, то по любому будет конфликт, так как в других ветках не будет изменений замерженой ветки.

Comment: А зачем вообще городить несколько веток для изменений в одном файле?

Comment: @Эникейщик Работаю по задачам, для каждой задачи создаю новую ветку на основе `dev`. Во всех этих задачах нужно работать с одним файлом **style.css**. Создаю мерж реквесты после выполнения каждой задачи, потом тестеры начинаю мержить все ветки в `dev` вот тут и натыкаются  на проблему. Я до этого действовал по другому: создал ветку, сделал нужные изменения, сразу отправил в `dev`, мержи не копились

Comment: Похоже, что вы и сами знаете ответ на свой вопрос, как надо делать, чтобы не было конфликтов :)

Comment: Если у вас фичи зависят друг от друга, то вам надо либо начинать новую фичу когда предыдущая закончена и смерджена, либо стартовать новую фичу от предыдущей фичи, а не от дева

Comment: @tym32167 Вот, я тоже так думаю, но не уверен что это правильно =)

Comment: правильного ответа нет в природе, выбирайте тот вариант, что устраивает вас и вашу команду

Comment: @Эникейщик Ветки не мержаться сразу в `dev` потому что нужно обязательно тестерам пройтись, потом они уже сами мержат.

Comment: @tym32167 Можете расписать вот это "Если у вас фичи зависят друг от друга, то вам надо либо начинать новую фичу когда предыдущая закончена и смерджена, либо стартовать новую фичу от предыдущей фичи, а не от дева "  как **ответ**? вдру кому пригодится

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все эти методологии - gitflow, git branching, etc - это не истина в последней инстанции, это просто рекомендации. То есть правильных и универсальных моделей ветвления исходников кода нет. Адаптируйте их для себя.

В вашем случае, если у вас фичи зависят друг от друга, то вам надо либо начинать новую фичу когда предыдущая закончена и смерджена, либо стартовать новую фичу от предыдущей фичи, а не от дева.

Comment: да согласен, тут проблема в самом процессе, который мы используем. Тестеры не хотят пропускать потенциаль забагованые фичи на dev, поэтому просят не мержить разработчиков =)

Comment: @Denisoed чтобы не пускать баги на дев, надо тестить фичи, а после мерджа тестить их ещё раз и/или делать регулярный (желательно автоматизированный) регресс дева, при этом не забывая про регресс релизов.

Comment: само собой разработчики тестирую свою работу, и уже после этого создают мерж, и пушат. Какой нибудь процесс командной разработки использовали?

Comment: @Denisoed когда я пишу про "тестить фичи" - я подразумеваю, что QA выполняет тестирование. То, что разрабы проверяют свою писанину - это само собой разумеющееся. Мне да, приходилось использовать и git branching, и gitflow, и кастомные способы. Сейчас, например, мы адаптировали gitflow под свои нужды и живем с этим.

Comment: Сейчас мы кстати работаем над одним проектом, где решили отказаться от gitflow, так как посчитали его слишком сложным в нашем случае, но бывает проскакивает мысль, что все таки есть преимущества у него, в виде фичей, и всем этим подходом. Я правильно понимаю, что, методология gitflow или как её правильнее назвать, создаёт новую фичу на основе всех ранее сделанных изменений, даже из веток которые не были ещё замержены в dev?

Comment: если у вас нет причин пользоваться gitflow, можно просто юзать git branching который тоже в фичами, но полегче. Мы так и делали поначалу, когда переезжали с SVN на git и было ещё не ясно, что нам надо, а что нет.  По поводу методологии, в [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) вы создаете фичи от девелоп ветки, но если в конкретной ситуации вам это не подходит, то, как я написал, можно изменить методологию под свои нужды

Comment: спасибо большое =)

Comment: @Denisoed пожалуйста