# Как правильно вести репозиторий в CD/CI?

Tags: git, git-branch, devops, ci-cd

Подскажите какие лучшие практики?

Вот у нас есть master ветка. То что там = продакшен.
Как что-то попадает в мастер ветку, система это чувствует и автоматически деплоит.
Есть вторая ветка "dev". То что там = тестовый staging сервер.
Как что-то попадает в "dev" ветку, система это чувствует и автоматически деплоит на тестовый сервер И прогоняет юнит тесты и e2e тесты.

Ну и вот вопрос, когда членам команды пооступает какой то таск, например "Напиши в шапке сайта "С новым годом'", откуда они должны форкаться? От master ветки, где все стабильно и 100% запустится у них на локалке, или от dev ветки, где все возможно не стабильно и тесты не прошли и сайт вообще не запускается, и тогда наш сотрудник не сможет приступить к изменению текста в шапке сайта, ведь сайт у него на локалке вообще не поднимится.

Но с другой стороны если он форкается от мастер ветки, то у него не будет текущей уже проделанной работы другими членами команды, конфликты своего кода и этой команды он должен решать. Он же ведь не увидет их код, как тогда решать конфликты?

Comment: Думаю это Вам поможет https://habr.com/ru/post/106912/

Comment: > или от dev ветки, где все возможно не стабильно и тесты не прошли и сайт вообще не запускается < - тогда у Вас проблема посерьезней.  В таком случае обычно нужно все бросить и начать лечить ветку, что бы она была рабочей. Если это обычное состояние этой ветки - это проблема команды. И как только это будет решено, сама проблема, поставленная в вопросе, исчезнет.

Comment: не силён в CI-CD, но выскажусь. Мне кажется разумнее тестить тематическую ветку фичи\фикса перед тем как сливать её в общую. Ну и при таком раскладе может быть одной общей достаточно будет.

Comment: "Мне кажется разумнее тестить тематическую ветку фичи\фикса перед тем как сливать её в общую" это теряет смысл всего CD/CI так как ты не можешь локально протестить, ведь смысл интеграционного тестирования это интеграция твоего кода с кодом других коллег и поимка поломок вызванных этой интеграцией.

Comment: хз поможет или нет, вот тут есть немного мыслей - [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881342/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012399/179763)

Answer (score 2):

Это уже как вы внутри команды довогоритесь. Нужно договориться, как вы скидываете различные типы изменений, исходя из важности/критичности вашего продукта (т.е. сколько вам будет стоить, если сайт упадет):

1. Плановые доработки через дев ветвь. Там проходячит все тесты и все такое.
2. Заплатки, которые не требуют тестирования (из разряда: поменять размер шрифта или текст на форме). Ответвились от мейн, поменяли шрифт и пул-реквест обратно.
3. Заплатки, которые требуют тестирования. Решаете когда должа она пойти:

   - Срочная - ветвь от мастера + прикручиваете тесты.
   - Клиент может подожать - включаете через план и ведете через дев ветвь.

Нормальная практика - создать hotfix ветвь после релиза и нацелить на нее тесты. Все срочные исправления через нее. Хотфиксы желательно и в дев ветвь передавать, чтоб команда в ней решала конфликты, а не при релизе в мастер.

Comment: "Заплатки, которые не требуют тестирования" -- Не, у нас такого не бывает, любой фикс или фитча обязана иметь хотя бы один тест =) но мысль вашу понял, спасибо

Comment: "Нормальная практика - создать hotfix ветвь после релиза" а разве если после релииза в продакшене обнаружен ХОТЬ ОДИН баг, это не ЧП и не повод откатываться до предыдущей версии? =)

Comment: @user403405 если обнаружен баг - это не чп. Откат или нет - это копромис, где из нас крови выпьют меньше: пока мы исправляем баг (т.е. баг маленький, он не влияет на функционал и народ потерпит) или пока откатываемся (система упала, не работает важный или часто используемый функционал). Если откат простой - это хорошо (вернулись и все), а если много компонентов откатывать - тут нужно принимать взвешенное решение. Да и ведь иногда присутствует раздел в релиз-ноутс: Известные проблемы...

Comment: хм, ну мы обычно делаем систему двустороннюю миграций и любую миграцию можно откатить назад), но в целом да, вы правы